# Create image from file, containing all points (imagemagick)

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have a large file (~100k strokes) with points like (Y,X), where coordinates set with leading zeros.

```
(001,042)
(012,706)
(412,760)
(001,790)
```

How can imagemagick make image 1000x1000 size with points draw by this coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

LOG_FILE=$1
IMAGE_FILE=$2
TMP_FILE="$LOG_FILE."

convert -size 1000x1000 xc:white $IMAGE_FILE

split -l 1000 $LOG_FILE $TMP_FILE -a 4

for file in $TMP_FILE*
do
    points=`cat $file | sed -r -e "s/\(//g" -e "s/\)//g" -e "s/^([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{3})$/point \2,\1/g"`
    convert $IMAGE_FILE -draw "$points" $IMAGE_FILE
done

rm $TMP_FILE*

echo "done!"
```

Usage:
./file.sh coord.log points.png